# Re-display dropdown list upon hovering over

Tags: jquery

I've triggered my dropdown list to dissapear once you mouseleave, but with it now being given display: none automatically, I need it to re-appear once you hover over again if you want to choose a new option.

This is in regards to the language drop-down at the top-right of my site

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1kpGc2G

This is what I've got right now controlling the hiding of the .menu

```
$('.menu').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.dropit-submenu').hide();
    });
```

I presumed it would just be another mouseon with .show but as the display: none is triggered it doesn't actually exist in order to be triggered back to an active state, so a little unsure.

Comment: Marked as off-topic while two replies were made, both of which work perfect. Can never please everyone on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.menu').hover(function() {
    $('.dropit-submenu').show();
},function() {
    $('.dropit-submenu').hide();
});
```

Using **CSS** only

```
ul.dropit-submenu{display:none;}
ul.menu li.dropit-trigger:hover ul.dropit-submenu{display:block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, the jQuery worked. While the CSS would work for hovering over, it wouldn't dissapear once I move away. All sorted now though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<div id="container">
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$("#container").hover(function(){
  $("select").show();
});
$("#container").mouseleave(function(){
   $("select").hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBnk/14/)